# Extracting max pixel value inside polygons in R

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp

I have been using

`extract(raster,polygons,na.rm=TRUE, fun=max)`

This generates pixel values from the pixel with max area inside polygons, i would like to extract the values from the pixel with max raster value inside each polygon, any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "the pixel with max area inside polygons"? what you've written finds the highest value pixel in each polygon from the raster. Do you want to find the coordinates of that pixel? Or something else?

Comment: I have circular forest inventory plots with raduis of 10m and i want to extract the max  raster value inside each plot. Not like "extract function" which extracts the raster value of the pixel with the biggest area inside each plot.

Comment: `extract(raster, poly, fun)` by default only returns pixels that have their centre in the polygon. If you include the `weights=TRUE` parameter then it returns all overlapping pixels with their relative overlap area, eg:  `raster::extract(rast, as(poly,"Spatial"), weights=TRUE, norm=FALSE)` - which returns a very similar thing (with identical values) to the `exact_extract` function.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by:

````
polys<-st_as_sf(polys)
res <- exact_extract(raster,polys,c('max'))```
````

Comment: Where does `exact_extract` come from? Its not in `raster` or `sf`.

Comment: It comes from a package with the same named exact_extract: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/exactextractr/versions/0.1.1/topics/exact_extract